# Retire nested filter wrong argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I want to make nested filtering. But return error. Is there another method of filtering? Use of this true?

Error output:
Wrong argument filter

/models/series/filter_season method:

```
def self.filter_season
    s = Tire.search('myindex', type: 'series') do
      query do
        filtered do
          query do
            all
          end
          filter do
            nested do
              path 'seasons'
              query do
                bool do
                  must do
                    term 'seasons.title', 'season 5'
                  end
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    s.results.each do|result|
      puts result.title
    end
```

end

Mapping setting:

```
  index_name 'myindex'
  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :title, type: 'string'
    indexes :seasons, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :title, type: 'string'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following answer on the issue [Nested query with filters test integration](https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/660)

`filter` method expects at least one argument where in your case it's receiving 0. Hence, the error.

Hope the article helps to resolve your issue.